# Whats the meaning of an error Integer number too large?

Tags: java, arrays

```
int [] array = new int[] {12, 6, 78, 9, 45, 08};
```

And this pop up
Main.java:7: error: integer number too large
int [] array = new int[] {12, 6, 78, 9, 45, 08};
^
1 error

Comment: Please, post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: When you write a number starting with a zero as you did in `08`, then Java is going to interpret it as an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) integer literal. In octal, there are only 8 digits, 0 to 7. The digit 8 is not a valid octal digit. Therefore you get the error. Solution: Write `8` instead of `08`.

Comment: But the output provided by our professor included the 08 in the list.